# Error: Length of `labels` should be as same as number of slices

Tags: r, visualization, heatmap, complexheatmap

I want to use [ComplexHeatmap](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/heatmap-annotations.html) to plot the "types" (type 1, type 2) and "subtypes" as top annotations using block annotation.
The row annotations would be the column names of `met.resolv`.

Code Part 1:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(GetoptLong)

clust.col <- c("#003f5c", "#374c80","#7a5195","#bc5090","#ef5675","#ff764a", "#ffa600", "#84E4F7", "#FFB480","#FDFD86", "#00a692")
meth.col <- c("#ff816f", "#ffbaae", "#f1f1f1", "#7e959e", "#004252")
met.immune.col <- c("#01444f", "#01575e", "#0d6a6a", "#217d74", "#38917c", "#52a482", "#6eb786", "#8eca89", "#b0dc8c", "#d5ed90", "#fdfd96")


pdf("Plots/heatmap_methylresolver.pdf")
ha = HeatmapAnnotation(
  name = "Sub-Cluster", empty = anno_empty(border = TRUE, height = unit(8, "mm")),
  foo = anno_block(gp = gpar(fill = clust.col), labels = unique(meta$clust))
)
la = rowAnnotation(foo = anno_block(gp = gpar(col=met.immune.col),
                                                 labels = colnames(met.resolv), 
                                                 labels_gp = gpar(col = "white", fontsize = 10)))
Heatmap(met.resolv, name = "SubClust", top_annotation = ha, 
        left_annotation = la, column_title = NULL)
```

Traceback:

```
Error: Length of `labels` should be as same as number of slices.
```

Code part 2:

```
group_block_anno = function(group, empty_anno, gp = gpar(), 
                            label = NULL, label_gp = gpar()) {
  
  seekViewport(qq("annotation_@{empty_anno}_@{min(group)}"))
  loc1 = deviceLoc(x = unit(0, "npc"), y = unit(0, "npc"))
  seekViewport(qq("annotation_@{empty_anno}_@{max(group)}"))
  loc2 = deviceLoc(x = unit(1, "npc"), y = unit(1, "npc"))
  
  seekViewport("global")
  grid.rect(loc1$x, loc1$y, width = loc2$x - loc1$x, height = loc2$y - loc1$y, 
            just = c("left", "bottom"), gp = gp)
  if(!is.null(label)) {
    grid.text(label, x = (loc1$x + loc2$x)*0.5, y = (loc1$y + loc2$y)*0.5, gp = label_gp)
  }
}
group_block_anno(meta[meta$type==1,], "empty", gp = gpar(fill = "#003f5c"), label = "type 1")
group_block_anno(meta[meta$type==2,], "empty", gp = gpar(fill = "#ffa600"), label = "type 2")

dev.off()
```

Data:

`met.resolv`

```
> dput(met.resolv[1:20,])
structure(list(Monocytes = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0691477875220381, 
0.0461824156116519, 0.00777223000960038, 0, 0, 0, 0.00165316191239164, 
0.0245461060386295, 0.026342142484403, 0, 0, 0, 0.0362473177899938, 
0, 0, 0.0615459951223746), `Dendritic Cells` = c(0, 0, 0.00772620422001257, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0480402297895918, 0, 0, 0.00898992233305366, 0.057888955860833, 
0.0362367878235371, 0, 0.0472205793224695, 0.0286203273050095, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Macrophages = c(0, 0.0664642500649833, 0, 0, 
0.0371204658284402, 0, 0, 0.0225187084795453, 0.0603416047052193, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0313730144635087, 0.0704265029977412, 0, 
0.00934366999330129, 0.0411264824824766), Neutrophils = c(0.173202855063056, 
0, 0, 0.0643464479529596, 0, 0.0187142163615865, 0.0117918312263748, 
0, 0, 0.115244141262919, 0.0520653071278115, 0.00997874098002133, 
0, 0.00754706466322519, 0.0885236230551497, 0.0144246971006176, 
0.000602296924347016, 0, 0.0195266392400734, 0.00343527794086701
), Eosinophils = c(0, 0.00809451621782635, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0026662337469062, 
0.0126433025837339, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00796674767545607, 
0), `Regulatory T cells` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Naive T cells` = c(0, 0.00984426904423764, 
0, 0.111694279700795, 0.0123267828167452, 0.0121761009946946, 
0.015487451006506, 0, 0.0231848393777138, 0, 0.00278269237244245, 
0.0200645732264692, 0, 0.0147361795082149, 0.0526711496398388, 
0, 0.00992032127196248, 0, 0, 0.030586635289606), `Memory T cells` = c(0, 
0.0312258875142767, 0.124409625779986, 0, 0.0135351004994425, 
0.0537156172200875, 0.0540049513012593, 0.0297542571267331, 0, 
0.0363411597373587, 0.0464268327265193, 0.0397546685980086, 0.0425232243321057, 
0.0491394530734343, 0, 0.0512205034016493, 0.023265025230139, 
0.130162735781893, 0, 0.00172924583134173), `CD8 T cells` = c(0.00282626493694126, 
0.0225524838253428, 0, 0.0030508623462426, 0, 0.0128041131453121, 
0, 0.102208367313482, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0668565430396047, 0.0343785834326558, 
0, 0.0418137510155405, 0.0039045724524825, 0.0142647475514386, 
0.0757110710314276, 0), `NK cells` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `B cells` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0158949534772194, 0, 0, 0.0174286273520171, 
0, 0, 0.0240398020597407, 0)), row.names = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93W.01A", 
"TCGA.4A.A93X.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A", 
"TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A", "TCGA.A4.7288.01A", "TCGA.A4.7583.01A"), class = "data.frame")
```

`meta`

```
> dput(meta[1:20,])
structure(list(clust = c("1a", "2a", "2b", "1b", "2a", "2c", 
"1c", "1c", "1b", "1d", "1e", "2c", "2b", "1c", "1e", "1c", "2c", 
"1f", "1c", "2a"), type = c("1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2"
)), row.names = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93W.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93X.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A", 
"TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A", "TCGA.A4.7288.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7583.01A"), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output (Example):

[image]

Comment: @TarJae I sincerely apologize. It was unintentionally deleted.

Comment: @TarJae Thank you. I hope you will take a shot at this new question.

Comment: Could you please show what kind of heatmap you already get, and what specific things you want to change on the heatmap. Otherwise it is a lot of guess!

Comment: @TarJae I've added a traceback (i.e., `Error: Length of `labels` should be as same as number of slices.). Did not generate any heatmap yet.
`